# How can I use Linksys WPSM54G print server as a bridge for another machine AND also share the printer

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, bridge, print-server

I have a Linksys WPMS54G currently sharing a printer via the USB port with the rest of my network via the wireless.

Is there any way to set it up so that the ethernet port is bridged over the wireless adapter portion? i.e., be able to uplink another machine or switch into the network via the WPMS54G's ethernet port?

**Update:**

The network architecture is as follows:

(1) Linksys WRT54G router that serves as a router, DHCP server, and wireless access point for the network.  Fairly standard configuration
(3) Laptops that are used throughout the house via wifi
(1) Linksys WPSM54G printer server that connects via wireless to the router, in a separate room with a printer attached to print seerver's USB port along with
(1) Un-networked desktop in the same room

Since the printer is plugged into the USB port of the WPSM54G, I am wondering if I can connect the desktop to the ethernet port of the WPSM54G and have it bridged over the wifi to the router.

The twist here is that the ethernet is initially used to connect the wireless print server to the router (for configuration, can't configure it wirelessly if you are initially on a encrypted network).  Now instead of using that ethernet port as a way to connect the print server to the network (via the router), I want to use the ethernet port as a way to connect another computer to the network, in effect bridging into the router via the print server, while still sharing the printer (attached via USB) through the print server.  If this is not clear, please comment.

To be clear, the computer I want to connect/bridge into the network does not have a wireless card, is far from the router, and I do not want to lay ethernet cable to connect it.  While I could certainly buy a legitimate wireless bridge to accomplish this, I figured since the print server already has an ethernet port, see if I can't use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this [thread on the Linksys support forums](http://forums.linksysbycisco.com/linksys/board/message?board.id=Wireless_Print_Servers&thread.id=2603) which seems to indicate its not possible.

This is the only information to date I've found and testing does not yield any results.